# AngularJS - Append element to each ng-repeat iteration inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using a ng-repeat inside a `<tr>` element together with a directive.

Html:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows" create-table>
    <td nowrap ng-repeat="value in row | reduceString>{{value}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('createTable', function () {
        return {

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var contentTr = scope.$eval('"<tr ng-show=&quot;false&quot;><td>test</td></tr>"');
                $(contentTr).insertBefore(element);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Although I can append a new `<tr>` element to each iteration, I'm not able to get angular code executed after it's been added to the DOM (for example the ng-show inside the `<tr>`). Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason why you don't get Angular binding inside your child is because **you lack [compiling](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) it**. When the link function runs, the element has already been compiled, and thus, Angular augmented. All you got to do is to `$compile` your content by hand. First of, don't eval your template, or you will lose your binding tips.

```js
app.directive('createTable', function ($compile) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var contentTr = angular.element('<tr ng-show=&quot;false&quot;><td>test</td></tr>');
      contentTr.insertBefore(element);
      $compile(contentTr)(scope);
    }
  }
});
```

**Another tip**: you never enclose your elements in jQuery ($). If you have jQuery in your page, all Angular elements are already a jQuery augmented element.

Finally, the correct way to solve what you need is to use the directive `compile` function (read ['Compilation process, and directive matching' and 'Compile function'](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)) to modify elements before its compilation.

As a last effort, read the entire [Directive guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), this is a valuable resource.