# Trying to transclude a select element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive, called **select** which replaces a select element.  To be more precise, it hides the select element and shows a custom dropdown. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4988/) in which I try to do that.

So, assume the following select element:

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption">
    <option ng-repeat="option in options" ng-bind="option.value"></option>
</select>
```

Now, this **select** directive should transclude this code into the following template:

```
<section>
    <div ng-transclude></div>
    <ol> <!-- custom dropdown/select -->
        <li ng-repeat="option in options" ng-bind="option.value">
    </ol>
</section>
```

And the directive:

```
myApp.directive('select', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'view/select.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
    };
});
```

Now, I see a couple of issues:

- the transclude seems to replace the whole template (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4988/))
- there is a weird `option` element
- how do I get the binded data, because I need that to create the custom dropdown

Hope someone can help me out here!

Thnx

UPDATE: Just to make clear, the reason I want to transclude the select element is because of the from magic. For example, if a user select an option in the custom dropdown, the directive will select this option in the hidden native select element. This way, the form stuff like $prestine is up2date

UPDATE2: found a way to do more or less what I need: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4996/). However, I do have to rename the directive now :( and it feels a bit like a hack the way I get the options array!

Comment: You might want to checkout the ng-options directive, it might give hints for creating what you want. ng-options is the "preferred" way of doing <select /> over ng-repeat

Comment: I don't see which problem ngOptions is going to solve ?

Answer (score 1):

If, as of Update2, you just want a less hackish way to access the options array, consider adding it as a property on the directive scope.

directive:
    `scope: { name: '@', options: '=' },`

html:
    `<selectx name="bar" ng-model="selectedOption" options='options'>`

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/5005/).

---

Alternatively, you could create the custom dropdown element [inside the link function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483324/angularjs-append-row-after-element-in-directive), and append it to the existing select element:
`myApp.directive('select', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var custom = angular.element('<section>\
                      <ol>\
                        <li ng-repeat="option in options" ng-bind="option.value">\
                     </ol>\
                   </section>');
            custom.insertAfter(element);
            $compile(custom)(scope);
        }
    };
});`

See it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/mY5MF/).

Of course, you can tweak the position of the original select if insertAfter isn't putting it where you want.

Comment: the original idea was to replace select elements with a custom dropdown. Adding the `options` attribute (and selectx too) moves away from that idea