# What does `element.next().insertBefore(element)` do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

I must be missing something very simple, but I'm not sure what it is yet.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18484058/15055) we have the code:

```
app.directive('createTable', function ($compile) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (element.next().length) {
                element.next().insertBefore(element);
            }

            var contentTr = angular.element('<tr><td>test</td></tr>');
            contentTr.insertAfter(element);
            $compile(contentTr)(scope);
        }
    }
});
```

The goal is to insert something after every element inside an `ng-repeat` directive.

What does this part do?

```
            if (element.next().length) {
                element.next().insertBefore(element);
            }
```

I read this as: "If there is an element, `X`, after `element`, then stick `element` before `X`". Yet it seems this would already be the case.

It clearly does something, since if I remove those three lines, all the elements get added to the end of the `tbody`, instead of being interspersed.. See [jsfiddle of the working version](http://jsfiddle.net/3gt9J/3/), and [the jsfiddle when it's commented out](http://jsfiddle.net/3gt9J/142/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

[`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/):

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements before the target.

Therefore, `$element.next().insertBefore($element)` swaps `$element` with its following sibling.

Comment: I may not be parsing this properly. Wouldn't `X` always already be before `X.next()`? `element` in this case is always one element.

Comment: Oh lol, I see. I misunderstood `X.insertBefore(Y)` to stick `Y` before `X`, not `X` before `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

It takes the next element and repositions it before the current element. Here's a demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #div1 { background-color: gray; }
      #div2 { background-color: red; }
      #div3 { background-color: blue; }
      #div4 { background-color: green; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
    <div id="div3">Div 3</div>
    <div id="div4">Div 4</div>

    <button id="btn">Rearrange</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#btn').on('click', function(e){
        var element = $('#div1');
        if (element.next().length) {
          element.next().insertBefore(element);
        }
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```