# Trying to use ng-click on an element created with element.append() during the postlink phase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to modify this angular library to add new features. https://github.com/southdesign/angular-coverflow/blob/master/coverflow.js
In doing so I need to be able to attach click events to the elements that it is creating. If you look at lines 64-73 you can see how an element is added to the DOM. Adding an ng-click to the template at line 72 has no effect. I'm guessing that is because angular has already begun the bootstrapping process and is overlooking this newly created ng-click. What is the proper way to do this? Should I modify the directive's template to use ng-repeat instead of using vanilla javascript and then go through and find each element to add the stylings to? Or is there a way to attach angular events using the current method?

Here's an example of how the directive is declared and how the coverflow plugin is initialized during the link (postlink) phase.

```
function coverflowDirective () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="coverflow-container"></div>',
        scope: { images: "=" },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // initialize
            scope.coverflow = new Coverflow({
                height:  320,
                width:   568,
                element: element,
                scope:   scope,
                images:  scope.images
            }).init();

            // Setup touch listeners
            element.bind('touchstart',  scope.coverflow.touchStart.bind(scope.coverflow));
            element.bind('touchmove',   scope.coverflow.touchMove.bind(scope.coverflow));
            element.bind('touchend',    scope.coverflow.touchEnd.bind(scope.coverflow));

            // Setup mouse listeners
            element.bind('mousedown',  scope.coverflow.mouseDown.bind(scope.coverflow));
            element.bind('mousemove',  scope.coverflow.mouseMove.bind(scope.coverflow));
            element.bind('mouseup',    scope.coverflow.mouseUp.bind(scope.coverflow));

        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.logIndex = function (index) {console.log(index);};
        }
    };
}
```

Here is my first attempt at adding an ng-click to the template.

```
Cover.prototype.template = function () {
    return '<div class="coverflow-cover" ng-click="console.log(1)" id="coverflow-cover-id-' + this.coverId + '"></div>';
};
```

Comment: Your line 72 is this `return '<div class="coverflow-cover coverflow-cover-id-' + this.coverId + '"></div>';`, I didn't see `ngClick` there. Please post your code in your question to make the question self-contained.

Comment: Just added an example. Also as a heads up the github link is not my library. I'm using it as a baseline to build a more feature rich coverflow library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in this question [AngularJS - Append element to each ng-repeat iteration inside a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728521/angularjs-append-element-to-each-ng-repeat-iteration-inside-a-directive) . It involves manually calling compile again on the element in the link function. Although it is now functional I'm still not sure if this is the best way to handle this. So I would love any feedback you may have.

```
function coverflowDirective ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="coverflow-container">' +
                      '<div id="coverflow-scrollbar"><div id="coverflow-scrollbar-handle"></div></div>' +
                  '</div>',
        scope: { images: "=" },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // initialize
            scope.coverflow = new Coverflow({
                height:  320,
                width:   800,
                element: element,
                scope:   scope,
                images:  scope.images
            }).init();

            // Setup touch listeners
            element.bind('touchstart',  scope.coverflow.touchStart.bind(scope.coverflow));
            element.bind('touchmove',   scope.coverflow.touchMove.bind(scope.coverflow));
            element.bind('touchend',    scope.coverflow.touchEnd.bind(scope.coverflow));

            // Setup mouse listeners
            element.bind('mousedown',  scope.coverflow.mouseDown.bind(scope.coverflow));
            element.bind('mousemove',  scope.coverflow.mouseMove.bind(scope.coverflow));
            element.bind('mouseup',    scope.coverflow.mouseUp.bind(scope.coverflow));

            // recompile after template generation
            $compile(element)(scope);

        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.logIndex = function (index) {console.log('index');};
        }
    };
}
```